# MS Teams: Getting Error "Please check the values of authorisation.permissions.resourceSpecific."

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit

We have created MS Teams application using fluent UI with Tab capability. We are performing few action like sending adaptive card to person/channel and creating tab with website link.

Application is started showing error while we click on the ADD while running in local environment.

After clicking on Add it call API `https://teams.microsoft.com/api/mt/part/emea-03/beta/users/apps/definitions/appPackage` which is failing with error code 400 with below response.

```
{"errorCode":"InvalidResourceSpecificPermission"}
```

While checking permissions we have following entries in the manifest.json

```
"authorization": {
    "permissions": {
        "resourceSpecific": [
            { "type": "Application", "name": "People.Read.All" },
            { "type": "Application", "name": "Chat.Create" },
            { "type": "Application", "name": "TeamsTab.ReadWrite.All" }
        ]
    }
},
```

I checked with documentation and found this permissions are correct. Kindly help us to resolve this issue as its blocking our development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permissions you've listed there are **Graph** permissions (e.g. see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-tabs?view=graph-rest-1.0) which lists `TeamsTab.ReadWrite.All`). As per the schema, you are trying to use these in the `resourceSpecific` list, which requires **Resource-specific consent** permissions instead. See here for the options: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/rsc/resource-specific-consent

Comment: I have removed TeamsTab permission but it didn't help. Can you guide what all permission is allowed as resourceSpecific list

Comment: Also if I remove from here where I need to add this. I am kind of new developing microsoft apps. Can you help me with some good tutorial where it explain this things.

Comment: TeamsTab was just an example - all 3 of your permissions are incorrectly Graph permissions. The allowed permissions are in the link I posted already, in my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Hilton said, you can only use the Resource-specific consent permissions listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/rsc/resource-specific-consent.

If you want to use Graph permission, you can follow the steps below:

1. Change the permissions in `templates\appPackage\aad.template.json` file:

   ```
    "requiredResourceAccess": [
        {
            "resourceAppId": "Microsoft Graph",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "People.Read.All",
                    "type": "Role"
                },
                {
                    "id": "People.Read.All",
                    "type": "Role"
                },
                {
                    "id": "TeamsTab.ReadWrite.All",
                    "type": "Role"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
   ```
2. Update remote AAD app permission through deploy command:
   [image]
3. Copy client id and client secret from AAD portal
   [image]
4. Follow the steps to get access token https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#4-get-an-access-token

Other reference:

[How do I get a Graph API token with higher permission than the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71468726/how-do-i-get-a-graph-api-token-with-higher-permission-than-the-user/71479617?noredirect=1#comment126344319_71479617)

https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/issues/5314